# check out a folder from perforce in python

Tags: python

Want to check out all the files present under dynamic_modules using Perforce checkout in python

```
self.dynamic_modules = 'adsp\dynamic_modules\*'

self.p4.run_edit('-c',self.cl,self.dynamic_modules)
```

Need to delete all the files, after checkout

```
self.p4.run_delete('-c',self.cl,self.dynamic_modules)
```

But, seem not working. What mistake I made here. How to check out the whole folder in perforce using python?

Comment: Is there any exception output?

Comment: Actually purpose is to delete all the files present in the folder dynamic_modules and then add the new files in the same folder, with perforce history. So, that perforce will understand I deleted old files and added the new files.

Comment: The backslash ? I mean the filepath contains backslash, shouldn't it be \\ ?

Comment: No it is local to machine. So one \ will work fine. tried will the individual file, works fine. But when trying for whole folder with single command failed

Comment: I think I need to try something like 
self.p4.run_delete('-v',self.cl,self.dynamic_modules)